# /etc/ accidently deleted in centos

Tags: centos

my server is not booting up because there is no `/etc/` folder in it. Looks like it has been removed accidently. I have been told by my host to do re installation of OS by booting rescue CD of operating system via KVM console. In the KVM console, I am stuck to a screen whose screenshot I am unable to post because I am not having enough reputation here.

Please tell me how to repair the my Centos 5 64 bit via KVM Console as I do not want to lose `/home/` folder because unluckily I am not having recent backups.

Comment: Boot the rescue CD, copy your `/home` directory to some other server, and then reinstall, then copy the files back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup of /etc, even an old one, you can try to restore it with a livecd. If you didn't change anything in the server configuration since the backup, that should help you get back on your feet.

If not, I suggest you to save your important data (`/home`, I guess) with a livecd. And reinstall.

Comment: No, i do not have any backup of `/etc`. I 'll have to reinstall it i guess but I do not have any knowledge of working with vm. I have access to my server via KVM console but It is stuck and keyboard is not working. I googled a lot but had no luck to find a guide which can help me to boot my server using live cd and then making a reinstall. I 'll appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: Don't have much experience with KVM. It seems you have to launch your VM with: `-cdrom /path/to/your/livecd.iso`. Did you try that?

Comment: How would I put `.iso` file into my server if it is not working and where 'll I run this command as my server is stuck at this screen. [link)(http://i.imgur.com/LGLhn.jpg)

Comment: My bad, I thought you where using linux qemu/kvm virtualization. It's obviously not the case. I don't know how/if you can boot on a CD through your KVM.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc` folder in basically any Linux / Posix system contains the complete system configuration including basically everything from hardware driver + network config to application software config. Without it and without a backup there is no chance to repair your Linux. Many files here are auto-generated at OS or application software installation time.

To recover the files in `/home/` you have the aready mentioned option to boot the server from a live CD (understood that this does not work for you) or the option to remove the server harddrive and connect it to a different server or PC. You could use e.g. a USB to SATA dongle (if its SATA) to be able to hook up the drive to a running PC. To read the Linux file systems, you will need special tools under Windows or another Linux. You could also boot a linux live CD on your own PC, if that works, and then hook up the drive. To read Linux file systems there is different tools freely available on the web, you could e.g. use [TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/) with the "Ext2+ Reiser" or the "Ext4" add on (see [addons](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm#filesys)). Be careful not to ruin the filesystems or you may loose all the data (there is always data recovery services available out there, but that will cost a bit). good luck!

Comment: I have managed to boot my server through live cd. Now please guide backing up my /home folder through live cd.

Comment: Is it possible that I upgrade my CentOS 5 to CentOS 6 and the the `/home/` remains untouched?

Comment: If `/home` is on a separate partition, you can reinstall without formatting this particular partition.

Comment: If you managed to boot your server on a livecd, you should be able to configure the network to make a copy of `/home` on a distant machine, through the network. You can use a command like that : `tar cj /home | ssh your_remote_server "cd /path/to/backup/dir; cat >home.tar.bz2"` to create a tarball of your `/home` and transfer it on a remote linux machine to `/path/to/backup/dir/home.tar.bz2`

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet I just looked into my disk's scenario via centos installation disc and it is showing `Type: Unknown`. I guess it is corrupt. Please look at the screenshot and let me know. If it is really corrupted, tell me the ways to recover `/home`.

screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8FSep.png

Comment: In shell of rescue mode, I ran `mount -t ext3 /dev/sda2 /temp` command to mount my sda2 partition into /temp folder. It returned the following error:

`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2`

checking it in syslog, i found `error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sda2.`

Comment: did you use a software raid on your disk(s)? from the screenshot it looks like you have two identically partitioned disks. Maybe try mounting `/dev/sdb2`. Also: Is it maybe not ext3, but ext4 or reiserfs or so?